# Counting tag and text characters in an HTML document in Ruby

Tags: html, ruby, parsing, sax

I need to parse an HTML document to count the number of characters for both tags (including attributes) and text in Ruby. For performance reasons, I don't want to use a DOM parser. I've looked at Nokogiri's SAX and Reader parsers and also to SaxMachine, but neither seems to offer me a way to track the parser's position in the input HTML.

Does anyone know a way to access this information in Ruby? Thanks in advance

Comment: To be more precise in my question, I need to count all the html characters and all the text, but I also need to know which tag the text is inside. Moreover, in the future I will probably need to filter which tags I need to process.

Comment: We can't really design your solution, the requirements you're giving are still vague. Can you provide an example of the output you're aiming for?

Comment: I've put another solution, is this closer to what you're looking for?

Answer (score 5):

**Input string**

```rb
html = <<-HTML
<html>

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  Hello world!
</body>

</html>
HTML
```

**Dumb solution**

Crude solution, it counts every alphabet character (ie. `</html>` count for 4 characters).

```rb
tag_count = 0
text_count = 0

in_tag = false

html.each_char do |char|
  case char
  when '<'
    in_tag = true
  when '>'
    in_tag = false
  when /\w/
    in_tag ? tag_count += 1 : text_count += 1
  end
end

puts "Text char count: #{text_count}"
puts "Tag char count: #{tag_count}"
```

**Nokogiri SAX solution**

This one could be easily translated to another language (eg. Java).

```rb
require 'nokogiri'

class HtmlCounter < Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Document

  attr_accessor :tag_count, :text_count, :comment_count

  def initialize(filtered_tags = [])
    @filtered_tags = filtered_tags
  end

  def start_document
    @tag_count = Hash.new(0)
    @text_count = Hash.new(0)
    @comment_count = 0
    @current_tags = []
  end

  def start_element(name, attrs)
    # Keep track of the nesting
    @current_tags.push(name)

    if should_count? 
      # Count the end element as well
      count_tag(name.length * 2)
      count_tag(attrs.flatten.map(&:length).inject(0) {|sum, length| sum + length})
    end
  end

  def end_element(name)
    @current_tags.pop
  end

  def comment(string)
    count_comment(string.length) if should_count?
  end

  def characters(string)
    count_text(string.strip.length) if should_count?
  end

  def should_count?
    # Are we in a filtered tag ?
    (@current_tags & @filtered_tags).empty?
  end

  def count_text(count)
    @text_count[@current_tags.last] += count
  end

  def count_tag(count)
    @tag_count[@current_tags.last] += count
  end

  def count_comment(count)
    @comment_count[@current_tags.last] += count
  end
end

# Don't count things in title tags
counter = HtmlCounter.new(["title"])
parser = Nokogiri::HTML::SAX::Parser.new(counter)
parser.parse(html)

puts "Text char count: #{counter.text_count}"
puts "Tag char count: #{counter.tag_count}"
```

output :

```rb
Text char count: {"body"=>12}
Tag char count: {"html"=>8, "head"=>8, "body"=>8}
```

Hope this helps.